# Manually reordering Bar Chart in R Highchart

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

I'm kind of new to `highcharter` and I'm trying to manually reorder the categories of a bar chart but I can't seem to find an immediate solution. I tried to reorder with `fct_relevel` but it doesn't work

My code looks something like this:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(x= rep(c("john", "Luke", "Tom", "Sarah", "Laura", "Stacy"), each = 2), 
                 y = round(runif(12, min=0, max=100)),
                 z = rep(c(2020, 2021), each = 6)
                 )

df %>% hchart("bar", hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = z))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Le50F.png)

Basically, I'd like to be able to manually set the order of the axis categories and reposition them as I prefer, for example by placing Luke last and Stacy first.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to use `hc_axis` to define the order of the categories.

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  hchart("bar", hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = z)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = list("Stacy", "john", "Tom", "Sarah", "Laura", "Luke"))
```

Output
[image]

Data

```
set.seed(123)

df <-
  data.frame(x = rep(c(
    "john", "Luke", "Tom", "Sarah", "Laura", "Stacy"
  ), each = 2),
  y = round(runif(12, min = 0, max = 100)),
  z = rep(c(2020, 2021), 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired result by setting your factor levels in the desired order and arranging your dataset:

```r
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x= rep(c("john", "Luke", "Tom", "Sarah", "Laura", "Stacy"), each = 2), 
                 y = round(runif(12, min=0, max=100)),
                 z = rep(c(2020, 2021), 6)
)

df %>% 
  mutate(z = as.character(z),
         x = fct_relevel(x, "Luke", after = 0),
          x = fct_relevel(x, "Stacy", after = Inf)) %>% 
  arrange(x) %>%
  hchart("bar", hcaes(x = x, y = y, group = z))
```

[image]